# && and || are not logical but conditional operators?

Tags: c#, operators, logical-operator

I am a bit confused by the MSDN C# documentation which states that `&` and `|` are logical operators and that `&&` and `||` are conditional operators.

I keep calling `&&`, `||` and `!` logical operators, so I am wrong?

Comment: It does seem illogical, but there is an important difference between the two classes, and it's critical that you not assume that, say, `|` is interchangeable with `||`, even though in many cases they can be interchanged with no apparent change in program behavior.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

> I am a bit confused by the MSDN C# documentation which states that `&` and `|` are logical operators and that `&&` and `||` are conditional operators. I keep calling `&&`, `||` and `!` logical operators, so I am wrong?

No; you're correct.

There are numerous small, mostly unimportant nomenclature errors in the MSDN documentation; I tried to get as many of them out as I could, but in cases where it is not egregiously wrong and misleading, it's not always a wise use of time. Go to the specification if you want a definitive statement about the name of a C# feature.

So: the relevant authority is the C# specification, which states in section 7.11:

> The `&`, `^`, and `|` operators are called the logical operators.

It then goes on to further break down the built-in logical operators into integer, enumeration, Boolean and nullable-Boolean logical operators.  There are also user-defined logical operators; see the spec for details.

In section 7.12 we have

> The `&&` and `||` operators are called the conditional logical operators. They are also called the “short-circuiting” logical operators.

So all of them are *logical* operators. Some of them are *conditional logical operators*.

What makes the conditional logical operators *conditional*?  One might make a specious guess that it is because they are typically used in *conditional statements* (`if`) or *conditional expressions* (`? :`).  The real reason is given by the specification:

> The `&&` and `||` operators are conditional versions of the `&` and `|` operators: The operation `x && y` corresponds to the operation `x & y`, except that `y` is evaluated only if `x` is not false. The operation `x || y` corresponds to the operation `x | y`, except that `y` is evaluated only if `x` is not true.

The conditional logical operators are thus named because *the right hand operand is evaluated conditionally depending on the value of the left hand operand.*

We can see this more vividly by noting that the *conditional logical operators* are just "syntactic sugars" for *conditional expressions*.  `x && y` is simply a more pleasant way to write `x ? y : false`, and `x || y` is simply a more pleasant way to write `x ? true : y`.  *The conditional logical expressions are actually conditional expressions.*

There is also a user-defined form of the conditional logical operator, and it is a little tricky. See the specification for details.

Further reading, if this subject interests you:

- https://ericlippert.com/2015/11/02/when-would-you-use-on-a-bool/
- https://ericlippert.com/2012/03/26/null-is-not-false-part-one/
- https://ericlippert.com/2012/04/12/null-is-not-false-part-two/
- https://ericlippert.com/2012/04/19/null-is-not-false-part-three/

Comment: So the fact that && cannot operate on bits has nothing to do with it?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Right, the fact that & can operate on bools, integer types or enum types but && only operates on bools has nothing to do with the choice of naming one of them the "conditional" form of the operator. The conditional operator is conditional because it has a conditional branch in its evaluation semantics.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: You can see this by desugaring the operators into their conditional form. `x && y` is neither more nor less than a sugar for the conditional expression `x ? y : false`.

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks a lot. The version with "conditional logical operators" is retired, the one I can find on MSDN does not mention that. But your explanation makes perfect sense.

Comment: @user970696: They're still called "conditional logical operators."  See the draft C# 6 specification here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#conditional-logical-operators

Comment: I am under the impression the term "short-circuit operator" is far more popular (and probably less ambigous) than "conditional operator" in the described sense.

Comment: @DocBrown: It is surely popular, but I've always found that name misleading; it seems to have been coined by someone who thought that a "short circuit" and a "short cut" to obtaining a result are the same thing. A short circuit is a dangerous fault which can quickly destroy an electrical system. We named "unsafe" blocks in C# "unsafe" because *they're dangerous if used incorrectly*; let's not give things cutesy but misleading value-laden names.  Don't even get me started on the Elvis operator. :-)

Comment: @EricLippert: While "short circuit" may sound scary to the general public, I don't think K&R were confused about the actual definition. In electrical engineering, shorting a circuit isn't always a dangerous fault, in fact we do it intentionally all the time. It just means to cut out an unwanted part of the circuit by giving the electricity a shorter path to follow.

Comment: `x&& y` is not exactly the same as `x ? y : false`.  In particular, operator overloading makes `&&` a rather interesting beast: "The operation x && y is evaluated as T.false(x) ? x : T.&(x, y) where T.false(x) is an invocation of the operator false declared in T, and T.&(x, y) is an invocation of the selected operator in &."

Comment: @CortAmmon: You'll want to be reading the following paragraph where I call out that the user-defined operator semantics are slightly different and that you should see the spec for details.

Comment: @CortAmmon Operator overloading makes *anything* a rather interesting beast.

Comment: Concerning the desugaring (but ignoring the short-circuiting), I actually find it very insightful to think of them as `x || y` := `x ? x : y` and `x && y` := `x ? y : x`. This is also how it works in weakly typed languages such as JS.

Answer (score 27):

In C# these are  *all* **logical operators.**

```
int x = 0xABCD & 0xFF // x == 0xCD
```

`&&` and `||` are called "**conditional** logical operators" because they are *short-circuiting.*

```
bool someOtherCondition = true;
if (x == 0xEF && someOtherCondition) // someOtherCondition is not evaluated, 
                                     // because x == 0xEF is false
```

Note that this terminology differs from language to language. In C and C++  `&&` and `||` are just [*Logical Operators.*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical) In Java, `&` and `|` are called [*Bitwise Operators*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html), while C and C++ classifies them as [*Arithmetic Operators*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic).

Comment: So is it incorrect to call && a logical operator? As I can see a lot of other sources, including books, actually do that

Comment: Thanks, that is funny, I quickly checked google books and basically not a single book distinguish them, they just call them logical operators. Maybe because they perform logical operations? (AND, OR, NOT, XOR)

Comment: Ah, so I found that that they are actually called "conditional logical operators", so seems like everybody is right. And for C++, MSDN uses for them just logical operators...not really consistent

Comment: The term "conditional logical operators"? When I googled that as a phrase, several books came up. But in the end, arent they doing logical operations? So why not call them logical operators, as you mention C and C++ do.

Comment: Microsoft is the only authority that matters.  See [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-or-operator): *"The conditional-OR operator* `||` *performs a logical-OR of its `bool` operands."*

Comment: The | and & operators operate on bools too.

Comment: @EricLippert: Yes, which is why I carefully chose my wording ("can" and "only").

Comment: @EricLippert Exactly, & and && differ just in short-circuiting, when applied to bools.

Comment: @RobertHarvey But for C++, Microsoft calls && LOGICAL OR.

Comment: I already stated that in my answer.

Comment: Yes, Microsoft is the authority, but the authoritative document is the specification. See section 7.12, **Conditional Logical Operators**.

Comment: The moral of the story being: *it's more important to understand precisely what these operators do than to be precise about their names.*

Comment: @EricLippert I wonder why they left this nomenclature and leave out "logical" in the newer versions.

Comment: @user970696: Does it really matter?  I personally prefer the term "Conditional Operators."  Why muddy the waters by adding more words that are not going to illuminate without reading the specification?

Comment: @user970696: There are many small nomenclature errors in the MSDN documentation; I attempted to correct them but I had many other pressing concerns.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Wel to me it does, I am trying to understand everything as much as I can :) As the difference between & and && is short circuiting, I still believe it is a logical operator, working with logical operands,

Comment: Focus on what the operators do, and stop obsessing with the vocabulary.  See also [Naming Considered Harmful](http://the-whiteboard.github.io/2017/11/21/naming-considered-harmful.html).

Comment: +1.  Everything listed in the question is just _operators_ that take one or two expressions and evaluate to a value.  The adjectives are unnecessary hair splitting.

Comment: @RobertHarvey [“Considered Harmful” Essays Considered Harmful](https://meyerweb.com/eric/comment/chech.html)

Comment: @Blrfl no, its not hair splitting. The key is that someothercondition is not evaluated. if someothercondition is a function with side effects, it wont be called. Also constructions like p!=NULL && p->a are valid  (and useful)expressions, while & would blow up.

Comment: @lalala  Understood, but the adjectives don't change the fact that both are different operators with different semantics.  If you wouldn't spend time debating whether `+` and `*` are additive vs. multiplicative or both are just arithmetic or they're just operators, arguing bitwise, non-short-circuiting vs. logical, short-circuiting is a similar waste of time.

Comment: @Blrfl actually short circuiting is quite unique (it only applies to 3 operators, if I am not wrong), and a lot of programmers are not aware of it, so in a sense even dropping this info (callng it a waste of time) is hiding this understanding further. I mean, e.g. is it obvious to you that they are *not* commutative?

Comment: @RobertHarvey while that article is pretty bad, it's not so bad as to suggest that we shouldn't have nomenclature for things that do actually need to be explained to people.

Comment: @lalala  I'm _not_ proposing that information about how the operators behave be hidden, although programmers unaware of the behavior of the operators they're using are effectively doing that for themselves.  I _am_ saying that the logical-vs.-conditional dichotomy in the question isn't meaningful.

Comment: I know this is old but it's worth noting that in Java `&` and `|` are logical operators i.e. they work on boolean values just without short-cutting.  The are overloaded such that it's only when you use them with numeric primitives that they are bitwise operators.

Answer (score -2):

The point is that `&` and `|` are **bitwise** operators, meaning they are applied to and yield bit string values. And bitwise is a very used term among programmers.

For instance `0xff & 0x00 == 0x00`, while `0xff | 0x00 == 0xff`.

And `&&` and `||` are applied to conditions, and yield the usual values of conditions; i.e. `true` and `false`.

For instance `true && false == false`, while `true || false == true`.

Therefore `&&` and `||` could be called **conditional** operators, even though that is not an usual term among programmers.

Of course, every C, C++, Java and C# programmer knows all that. But I guess that the misunderstood happens because "conditional operator" is not a term frequently used by us programmers.

Comment: _Of course, every C, C++, Java and C# programmer knows all that._ That's a very rude thing to write, implying the OP is stupid. Same by writing _us programmers_, you exclude the OP. Please don't do that.

Comment: I don't think that your *later* answer brings any added value *after* the Eric Lippert's accepted answer, and furthermore is incorrect in the meaning of not understanding the point of the question.

Comment: @DarkDust Every C, C++, Java and C# programmer should understand those operators. This is not being rude **but a fact**.

Comment: @Phil1970: OP does seem to understand these operators, it's about clarification of the _naming_. In this light, and having emphasized the relevant terms in Hilton's answer, that sentence of his can be interpreted as meaning _every programmer knows about these naming details, but you don't_. This _is_ wrong (as can be seen in the discussions of the other answers) and its phrasing is rude.

Comment: Dear all, I'm sorry if my answer looked rude. English is not 1st language. In any case, I never intended to imply that the OP was not a programmer. Au contraire, I meant that he or she was confused by an unusual naming in the text he or she read. All that I tried to do was to  clarify the unusual naming by program fragments.